# Help running FightCade application?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, wine, games

I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to get the application FightCade (fightcade.com) up and running. I followed the directions in the `readme` file, but have run up against a wall:

I used the terminal to download wine and all the other things, and the readme suggests I should just be able to type `./fightcade` to run the application. But I just get the message `No such file or directory.`

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate to the directory in which the `fightcade` executable is located before running `./fightcade`:

```
cd /path/to/fightcade/executable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same thing.
The latest version comes with an installer so you just need to execute

```
sudo ./linux-install.sh
```

To execute it should just be `./fightcade`

There is a WiKi post about it here.
https://code.google.com/p/groovyarcade/wiki/FightCade_Install_HowTo?ts=1430474430&updated=FightCade_Install_HowTo